# button show or hide content - angular BehaviourSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a button, that on every click should display or hide content

HTML:

```
<button (click)="showHide()">
    {{ content$ ? 'Hide'  : 'show'  }}
</button>
<div *ngIf="content$" >
    CONTENT
</div>
```

TS:

```
readonly content$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
showHide(): void {
    this.content$.next(true);
}
```

and this code does not give any error, but it always displays content and I cannot hide it, any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow!

You are correctly set a new value into the `BehaviorSubject`, and with: `*ngIf="content$"`you are just checking that `BehaviorSubject` exists.

In order to get the content you have to:

```
<div *ngIf="content$ | async; let content">
  CONTENT
</div>
```

With `let content` you can access to your subject's value, in case you have to ;)

You can have more information about on [AsyncPipe doc](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Comment: that helped, but now i can show the content, but hide doesent work, once i display content i cannot hide it –

Comment: Cause your `showHide` method just show it (`this.content$.next(true)`). 
You have to customize your logic in order to switch from true to false, a thing like this: `this.content$.next(!this.content$.getValue())`

Comment: Thanks!!! but now my text inside button is always the same, it does not respond on the content$ changer

Comment: You have to check the value of the `BehaviourSubject` and based on it, you have to change the label. Pretty similar to the content div

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the async pipe to read the observable value.

```
<div *ngIf="content$ | async" >
 CONTENT
</div>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

Comment: that helped, but now i can show the content, but hide doesent work, once i display content i cannot hide it

Comment: Your method that show or hide the content, is always changing the behaviorSubject to true, you need to change the value to the opposite value when you click that button